# Pandas turn a column with multiple datatypes into a column with one datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I do have a problem with one column of my dataset. My "Tags" column is an object type in pandas. The Tags are in a list. Now i want to apply a lambda function to get the length of the list. I got following error message:

> object of type 'float' has no len()

I analyzed the dataset and found that I have str, float and None types. I queried the None Types in my Lambda function, using an if clause.
Now my problem is, I don't know how to unify the other datatypes, that all datatypes are of type List.

I tried the .astype function, but there I get the following error message:

> data type 'list' not understood

Maybe someone can provide me an answer :)

Edit:

```
video_df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x is None else len(x))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\PythonTutorial\Analysis\analysis.ipynb Cell 54' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 video_df['tags'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x is None else len(x))

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Sample just one single value:

```
'[\'god of war 3\', \'gow\', \'santa monica studios\', \'sony\', \'msony computer entertainment\', \'ps3\',\'1080p\']'

    ['bauen',
     'insel',
     'instrumente'
]
```

Edit: Celteron - ideal output
Col   current dataset
len 1 ideal output
len 2 current output with this functio
Output:

```
          col  len1  len2
0 '[1, 2, 3]'   3.0  7.0
1         NaN   NaN  <NA>
2          []   0.0     0
3   [1, 2, 3]   3.0     3
4     [1,2,3]   3.0   didnt found one output yet 
5           a   NaN   1.0
6      [test]   1.0   1.0

(col index 4: strangly float objecttype in pandas)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data (ideally as DataFrame constructor)

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two main options.

1. Use `str.len` which works on all iterables (strings, lists, tuples...)
2. Use a loop and check whether you have instances of lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,float('nan'),[],[1,2,3],(1,2),'a',['test']]})

# option 1
df['len1'] = df['col'].str.len()

# option 2
df['len2'] = [len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else pd.NA
              for x in df['col']]
```

Output:

```
         col  len1  len2
0          1   NaN  <NA>
1        NaN   NaN  <NA>
2         []   0.0     0
3  [1, 2, 3]   3.0     3
4     (1, 2)   2.0  <NA>
5          a   1.0  <NA>
6     [test]   1.0     1
```

Comment: A nice way to use `str` accessor on lists!

Comment: Heyy, Thanks for the advices ! :) The method with df[].str.len() counts the length of the strings / characters. My need is to count the entrys the lists, but my lists are sometimes string and sometimes list objects etc. as i mentioned. For example the value in my df.iloc[123213]['tags'] is ['trailer']. If i apply the function as mentioned above the value I get is -> 11.0 - instead it should be 1

Comment: @Celteron do not be abused by the name `str.len`, if the objects are lists this will return the list length, i.e. the number of entries ;) I updated the answer with another example for clarity

Comment: @mozway hey thanks for your help :) 
Iam sorry, i reviewed the data more and saw that the function work like intended. 
Still i have the problem, that my dtypes of the columns are objects like List, str etc. to get the len i need them to be list. 
Tried meanwhile to change there types, but i dont find a solution

Comment: @Celteron have you checked my second solution? If you consider my example dataframe, what would be your ideal output?

Comment: @mozway i add this in the answer above, aswell here
Edit: Celteron - ideal output
Col   current dataset
len 1 ideal output
len 2 current output with this functio
Output:
```
          col  len1  len2
0 '[1, 2, 3]'   3.0  7.0
1         NaN   NaN  <NA>
2          []   0.0     0
3   [1, 2, 3]   3.0     3
4     [1,2,3]   3.0   didnt found one output yet 
5           a   NaN   1.0
6      [test]   1.0   1.0

(col index 4: strangly float objecttype in pandas)
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting makes it ambiguous

Comment: @mozway no problem :), i updated my question thread

Answer (score 2):

##### New Answer

@mozway pointed out that `df['Tags'].str.len()` gracefully handles objects with undefined length!

##### Old answer

One workaround is to define a custom function to handle the `TypeError` which arises from objects with no defined length. For example, the following function returns the length of each object in `df['Tags']`, or -1 if the object has no length:

```
def get_len(x):
    try:
        return len(x)
    except TypeError:
        return -1

df['Tags'].apply(get_len)
```

Comment: You can already do pretty much the same with `df['Tags'].str.len()`, or for filling with -1: `df['Tags'].str.len().fillna(-1, downcast='infer')`

Comment: hey, Thanks for the advices ! :) The method with df[].str.len() counts the length of the strings / characters. My need is to count the entrys the lists, but my lists are sometimes string and sometimes list objects etc. as i mentioned.

For example the value in my df.iloc[123213]['tags'] is ['trailer']. If i apply  the function as mentioned above the value I get is -> 11.0 - instead it should be 1